# Trying to pass a parameter in ASP.NET ! Parsing error

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I am trying to pass a parameter from a page to another. I am getting parsing errors (Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. )

This is the code :

```
<a runat="server" href="~/ProductDetails.aspx?IDProduct=<%# Eval("IDProduct") %>">
   <asp:Label Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="Red" runat="server">get specifications</asp:Label>
</a>
```

I am getting errors at `IDProduct=<%# Eval("IDProduct") %>!`
How should i write it ?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to handle such cases is to make the whole attribute value generated inside `<%# %>`. Also note the updated quoting pattern - single quotes around attribute value, and double quotes inside `<%# %>`.

```
href='<%# "~/ProductDetails.aspx?IDProduct=" + Eval("IDProduct") %>'
```

Comment: It works with the second solution. i wrote everything inside <%# %>. Thank you

Comment: @user1747659, then I should rather remove it, not to deceive others who might find this post. Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this
`<a runat="server" href="~/ProductDetails.aspx?IDProduct="<%# Eval("IDProduct") %>>`

Comment: While this might be the correct thing to do, you should try to provide an explanation along with your answer. Pure code sometimes is not self-explanatory.